# How to represent/read a cube in dxf file?

Tags: file-format, cad, dxf

Trying to open a dxf file format (actual project in C++), I could understand the basic structure of the file, but I can't manage to find how a cube is actually represented.

[image]

For a cube in CAD, I expect at least 9 values:

- X Y Z position
- A B C rotation
- W H D size of the cube

I expect X, Y, Z, A, B and C to be in the ENTITY section,

But Looking at example files, I see many settings, the preview image (taking a significant space in the file), layouts, etc.. But nothing that I can match to how the cube is actually build.

---

### Question:

**How to represent/read a cube in a dxf file?**

---

### More info

Here is the documentation about the file format:

http://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-235B22E0-A567-4CF6-92D3-38A2306D73F3

Here is an example of file with a cube (created with BricsCAD). Unfortunately, I can't embed the file, as it is too big.
The "cube" is of 20mm x 25mm x 30mm.

https://download.escain.org/example_cube_20_25_30_mm.dxf

I checked LibreCAD source-code, but it does not manage 3D models. Also, libdxfrw library is too generic (it just call the interface callback with the full Entity data).

https://github.com/LibreCAD/LibreCAD_3
https://github.com/LibreCAD/libdxfrw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cube is embedded binary ACIS data (3DSOLID) and can not be interpreted without the libraries from Spatial Inc. For more information see my answer to another question:
[How I can parse nurbs surface from dxf file? Or do you know library(for js, if exists or any other language) for parsing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66272618/how-i-can-parse-nurbs-surface-from-dxf-file-or-do-you-know-libraryfor-js-if-e/66274913#66274913)

EDIT: Find binary data of ACIS entities

Starting with R2013/AC1027 Modeler Geometry of ACIS data is stored in the section `ACDSDATA` in a `ACDSRECORD` these records have no handle, instead they have an ID. The record of your 3DSOLID starts at line 22393 and has the ID 10:

```
0
ACDSRECORD
90
1
2
AcDbDs::ID
280
10
320
D2            <<< handle to 3DSOLID
2
ASM_Data
280
15
94
9259          <<< size in bytes
310
41534D2042696E61...   <<< binary data as multiple tags of group code 310
```

This is your 3DSOLD with handle `D2` which starts at line 2187:

```
0
3DSOLID
5
D2      <<< handle of your 3DSOLID
330
1F
100
AcDbEntity
8
0
100
AcDbModelerGeometry
290
0
2
{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
100
AcDb3dSolid
350
0
```

As you see there is no association from the 3DSOLID to the binary content as `ACDSRECORD` in the `ACDSDATA` section.

I have no knowledge of a table (DICTIONARY) that links this data together. The only way I know is to search all `ACDSRECORD` in the `ACDSDATA` section for links (group code 320) to ACIS objects.

FYI: In DXF versions prior to R2013 the ACIS data is stored in the entity itself as ascii text with a lousy xor "encryption". All my Knowledge about the DXF format is baked into my Python package: [ezdxf](https://github.com/mozman/ezdxf).

Comment: I read this, but I expected someone to have discovered the basics, or some non-official base on which to work.

Comment: It would already be a big benefit if I could see the ACIS data block somewhere (which I could not find). So at least I know where to look. DXF documentation speak about Block 1 and 3, but none of those are in the entity sections.

Comment: added additional information how to find the binary data

Comment: Ohh! that is wonderful! I also found some info about the ACIS SAT, that supposedly is very similar to SAB. I will try to use the same xor decription than the header and see.

Comment: I found that the SAB format in the DXF is just HEX-encoded. I found old documentation about ACIS format, which was enough to understand most of the SAB data.